# how to resize uploaded image with multer

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, multer

after posting a form and before saving the image ( uploaded from the form), I want to resize it so that when it will be using it, it will be shown with the right size on the website.

```
const fileStorageEngine = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null, "./public/images");
    },
    filename: (req,file,cb)=>{
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}--${file.originalname}`);
    }
});
```

this is my code defining destination and filename, I was wondering where could I check for it's size.

Comment: Maybe you need to define your own custom MUlter storage to be able to resize an image before saving it on a disk, see https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md